# Yii2 ActiveDataprovider get the related fields data

Tags: php, yii2

I have setup my dataprovider with left join as

```
$trucks = TblTrucks::find()
                  ->leftJoin("tbl_checks", "tbl_checks.truck_id=tbl_trucks.id")
                  ->Where(["town"=>$town])

                  ->andWhere(["truck_status"=>6])
                  ->andWhere(["between","tbl_trucks.created_at", $ts1, $ts2 ]);


    $provider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $trucks,
        'pagination' =>false,
    ]);
```

Now am getting thje data via

```
return $provider->getModels();
```

This returns only tbl_trucks data how can i still get the data in the tbl_checks

Comment: I think you can get data you need from relations specified in your ActiveRecord classes.

Comment: how specifically since getModel() doesnt

Comment: I'm not sure but I think you can call for example `$model->getChecks()` on each model you get from `$provider->getModels()` assuming you have `getChecks()` method which returns related records in your `TblTrucks` class

Comment: add `tblTrucks` model.

Answer (score 0):

To get related field in model first of all your must have relation model `TblChecks` define relation in model `TblTrucks` acording to [documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html#relational-data)
In you case it will be some like that:

```
public function getTblChecks()
{
    return $this->hasOne(TblChecks::className(), ['truck_id' => 'id']);
    //or, depending on the type of relation (on-to-one or one-to-maty) 
    return $this->hasMany(TblChecks::className(), ['truck_id' => 'id']);
}
```

Than use method `joinWith`:

```
$trucks = TblTrucks::find()
              ->joinWith(['tblChecks'])
              ->Where(["town"=>$town])
              ->andWhere(["truck_status"=>6])
              ->andWhere(["between","tbl_trucks.created_at", $ts1, $ts2 ]);
```

And then you can get relation field just call it:

```
$models = $provider->getModels();
$models[index]->tblChecks->needed_field
```

But if you need just array of modesl acording to your query you dont have to use `ActiveDataProvider` just call method `all()`
For example:

```
$trucks = TblTrucks::find()
              ->joinWith(['tblChecks'])
              ->Where(["town"=>$town])
              ->andWhere(["truck_status"=>6])
              ->andWhere(["between","tbl_trucks.created_at", $ts1, $ts2 ])->all();
```

And in var `$trucks` you will have array of models `TblTrucks` with relation models (`TblChecks` in this case) acording to your query.